# Qt: when to use inheritance vs. setting attributes?

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance, qt5

I'm a relative newbie to Qt. One issue that comes up frequently is I'm often unsure of whether to use inheritance or not. For example, to set up and customize a QFrame, I could either instantiate a QFrame and set all its attributes (including child objects). Alternatively, I could subclass qframe and put all the setup code in the class's constructor (or a function that the constructor calls).

My intuition is that the choice is dependent on the level of complexity, but the dividing line isn't always clear cut. Are there best practices on this?

Comment: If it's just about setting a couple attributes, I'd go for a free function FunkyFrame* createFrame(QWidget* parent); or somesuch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether to use inheritance or not should not usually be decided on how to initialise an object of a class, but rather what type of object you're needing to create and whether or not you are **extending the class**.

Using an example of a Shape class that is an abstract base class, we can inherit this to make classes such as Triangle, Circle, Rectangle etc, because each inherited class is a type of Shape and each class adds **new attributes and or functionality** to the existing base class.

However, if we were to add a class of Square, some would argue that it's not required, but it adds to the functionality of ensuring the sides are equal, so that's a valid argument for inheritance.

In your example of QFrame, I personally wouldn't recommend using inheritance just to set-up the object, but would create a separate initilization function in either the parent class, if there is one, or main. If, however you're going to add attributes or functionality to create a different type of QFrame, then inheritance is the way to go.

Realistically, so long as your code works, there's no real right or wrong method, but trying to stick to techniques for what they were designed for will make your code easier to read and more easily maintainable.

Answer (score 4):

Best practice? Don't abuse inheritance. Inheritance is mostly about polymorphism. Sometimes code reuse. But **never** just to initialize an object.

Readability is one thing. Flexibility, maintainability and extendability are other important features to keep in mind.

May I point to this article:
  http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill06.htm

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting question. My experience is with Qt4. I'm gradually moving to Qt5 and learning Qml since this seems to become Qt stardand way to write GUI.

I use Qt in my work and what we do is to prefer settings attributes avoiding inheritance. The problem is that are some Qt classes that you have to inherit to return some values in it's protected methods. `sizeHint` is an example.

Inherit from Qt sometimes means to write extra code and call super methods to get the default behavior of the class and sometimes one might forget to call a super method and you'll get undesired behavior.

I try to use composition whenever I can.

Answer (score 1):

I can only answer you from my personal experience. And the main factors that lead to derive a class are these:

- Your class has grown complex, with a lot of particular settings (styles, sizes, attributes). Fixing them on the constructor is easy and makes the code more readable and organized.
- You feel that it seems logical to move inside it some methods that you are implementing outside. For instance, some response to events or filters.
- You find useful to define some slots as response to external signals.
- You find useful to implement signals that arise from your widget.
- You find useful to derive new classes from this and/or reuse it in other applications.

And the most important fact: **try to make your code the most readable and organized as you can**. Remember that the compiler probably will change the whole program because of its optimizer!!!